# Add two integers up and print the result, when i use `int` it's right but when i use `double` it's wrong?

Tags: c++

Input two integers a and b, 1<=a,b<=10^6. Print their sum.

code using int:

```
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
cout << a + b;
```

code using double:

```
double a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
cout << a + b;
```

After I submit these code to the online judge website, the first code can pass all 5 cases, but the second can pass only 3 and the other 2 are wrong answer.

But since `double` include the range of `int`, why can't it pass some of the cases that `int` can? I understand using `double` instead of `int` may be a waste of memory, but I think this should not cause any mistake.

Besides, when using `double`, if I print the result using `printf("%.0lf", a + b);`,it can also pass all 5 cases.

I know this is an extremely simple program but i can't figure out why it may be wrong using double.

Comment: Hey, you are either using **C** or **C++** but not both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: @Magisch This has nothing to do with floating point accuracy (double-precision floating point can represent all 32-bit integers accurately).

Comment: @interjay What do you mean "accurately"? `double` can only represent approximate values of all 32-bit integers, I wouldn't necessarily call that "accurate".

Comment: [Here's](http://ideone.com/vGUTWo) an example showing how it fails.

Comment: @zenith You are incorrect. `double` can represent all values of 32-bit ints 100% accurately, without any imprecision.

Comment: [Here's a simple example](http://ideone.com/IX57wg) that show the possible differences. You need to use the proper [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) to format the output correctly.

Comment: The online judge website probably expects to output to be in a specific format, and doesn't accept e.g. scientific notation.

Comment: @interjay Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thank you very much!

Comment: @zenith you are right. The problem is caused by scientific notation when the result is too large as interjay and Joachim Pileborg show in their example. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When the result is larger than or equal to 10^6, it would be printed by `cout` in scientific notation which is not accepted by the online judge.

Comment: As @Joachim Pileborg pointed out use the IO manipulators to change the format.
cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << a + b;
Just update as needed as discussed in the link he provided